# speeding up compile time using an usb key?

Tags: performance, compilation

As compilation is mostly reading small files, I wonder if buying a fast usb key to work on can  speed up compilation time compared to a standard SATA drive, and with a lower price than an SSD drive (16Gb keys are < 30$).

Am I right ?

PS: I working with .Net, VS and the whole MS' tools, but I think this is true for all languages...

***[Edit]*** According Toms's hardware, a recent [hdd drive read access time is near 14ms](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/257557-14-samsung-spinpoint-read-access-time-tests-spikes) average where the [slowest USB key is 1.5ms](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/usb-thumb-drive-charts/Read-Access-Time-h2benchw-3.13,2289.html)

That's why I'm wondering if my hypothesis is right

Comment: Compiling is an integer problem.  You can easily tell from Taskmgr.exe, Performance tab.  If a cpu core is pegged at 100% then it is not being slowed down by I/O.  But sure, you can get some speedup from an SSD.  Simplest way to find out how much is just by trying it.

Comment: I was considering buying an USB key, not a SSD drive which price is too expensive. And buy to try is not more an option

Comment: What was your finding? SSD drives are still expensive here in Australia. I'm looking to do the same for Java (maven) builds. Considering holding my whole `.m2` cache on the drive along with projects.

Comment: As I said in my answer, the price of a SSD drive is now very affordable. I don't know the price in Australia, but in europe it's very affordable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One year later, SSD drives cost has melt.

This is now the simplest solution, as you can host the operating system and all the dev tools on a fast SSD drive, which costs less than $ 120 (100 €)

Answer (score 0):

The specifications on [Wikipedias SATA page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Comparison_with_other_buses) suggest otherwise. The SATA revision 3.0 is 50% faster than USB 3.0 according to the spec.

Comment: In term of bandwith, yes. But I'm not targeting to speed up reading **one** file, but hundred of small files. I think access time is far more important than raw performance. Check my edit for benchmarks